# Facebook page webhook data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

In facebook developers i set up page webhook in my app. All work fine and i am getting webhook updates when someone send message to my page. JSON:

```
{
  "object": "page",
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": 859996317460158,
      "time": 1461153660752,
      "messaging": [
        {
          "sender": {
            "id": 1197760990255914 // page scoped user id
          },
          "recipient": {
            "id": 859996317460158
          },
          "timestamp": 1461153660704,
          "message": {
            "mid": "mid.1461153660696:7daeb8be2403ec7835",
            "seq": 64,
            "text": "1111111111111111111"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanna get real (facebook) user id from person who wrote this message. But from api query `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/1197760990255914?access_token=<page_access_token>`
i can get only `first_name, last_name, profile_pic` fields.
How can i get user id and message (dialog) history from page scoped user id?

Comment: Apps are not supposed to deal with “global” user ids any more (unless the user logged in to the app before API v2.0 was announced already.) Facebook has introduced app-scoped/page-scoped user ids for a reason. App-scoped ids can be “connected” by adding several apps to the same business; if that is possible for pages as well, I don’t currently know.

Comment: @row248 you can't get ‘user id’ unfortunately. Very annoyng.